# How to make longtable environment fit within margins without changing to different environment?

Tags: longtable

I've looked around the forum and I've found some questions on this, but most of them suggest changing to a different environment. I need longtable as it will be split over 2 pages. User @Zarko asked me to give a MWE:

It compiles like this:
[image]

And here is the MWE (all of the extra stuff is because this is extracted from a longer document):

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{float}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 8in}]{geometry}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\newcommand{\degree}{\ensuremath{^\circ}}
\newcommand{\quotes}[1]{``#1''}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[columns=3, title=Alphabetical Index, intoc]
\usepackage[spanish,es-nodecimaldot]{babel}
\usepackage[sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Bibfile.bib}
\DeclareMathOperator\grad{grad}
\DeclareMathOperator\prima{'}
\DeclareMathOperator\sen{sen}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{position=bottom}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[per-mode=symbol]{siunitx}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\usepackage{longtable}
\interfootnotelinepenalty=10000
\usepackage[spanish]{minitoc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{group-digits=false}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{ |L{4cm}|c|c|c|c| }
    \caption[Datos de los alerones y spoilers de aviones semejantes.]{\label{aler_spoil}}
    \endlastfoot
        \hline
        \multicolumn{5}{|c|}{\textbf{Alerones y Spoilers\footnote{Las definiciones son análogas a las dadas para dispositivos hipersustentadores.}}} \\
        \hline
        & Proyecto & \vtop{\hbox{\strut \makebox[2.5cm][c]{A319-100}\par }\hbox{\strut \makebox[2.5cm][c]{\cite{A319APM,JanesA319,A319TC,EurocontrolA319}}\par}} & \vtop{\hbox{\strut \makebox[2.5cm][c]{B737-700}\par }\hbox{\strut \makebox[2.5cm][c]{\cite{B737APM,JanesB737,B737TC,EurocontrolB737}}\par}} & \vtop{\hbox{\strut \makebox[2.5cm][c]{A220-300}\par }\hbox{\strut \makebox[2.5cm][c]{\cite{A220APM,JanesA220,A220TC,EurocontrolA220}}\par}} \\
        \hline
        Número de alerones por semiala & I/B: 0 O/B: 1 & I/B: 0 O/B: 1 & I/B: 0 O/B: 1 & I/B: 0 O/B: 1 \\
        \hline
        Número de spoilers por semiala\footnote{Al igual que con los slats, consideramos que los spoilers externos conforman un único dispositivo. De esta manera, empleamos los subíndices $sp\;I/B$ y $sp\;O/B$ para referirnos a los spoilers interno y externos, respectivamente.} & I/B: 1 O/B: 4 & I/B: 1 O/B: 4 & I/B:1 O/B: 5 & I/B:1 O/B: 4 \\
        \hline
        Envergadura (m) & \vtop{\hbox{\strut \makebox[3cm][c]{$b_a = 5.9214$}\par }\hbox{\strut \makebox[3cm][c]{$b_{sp\;I/B} = 3.1275$}\par}\hbox{\strut \makebox[3cm][c]{$b_{sp\;O/B} = 11.2382$}\par}} & \vtop{\hbox{\strut \makebox[3cm][c]{$b_a \approx 5.2692$}\par }\hbox{\strut \makebox[3cm][c]{$b_{sp\;I/B} \approx 2.7943$}\par}\hbox{\strut \makebox[3cm][c]{$b_{sp\;O/B} \approx 10.8577$}\par}} & \vtop{\hbox{\strut \makebox[3cm][c]{$b_a \approx 5.9551$}\par }\hbox{\strut \makebox[3cm][c]{$b_{sp\;I/B} \approx 4.7014$}\par}\hbox{\strut \makebox[3cm][c]{$b_{sp\;O/B} \approx 10.3430$}\par}} & \vtop{\hbox{\strut \makebox[3cm][c]{$b_a \approx 5.8881$}\par }\hbox{\strut \makebox[3cm][c]{$b_{sp\;I/B} \approx 4.0107$}\par}\hbox{\strut \makebox[3cm][c]{$b_{sp\;O/B} \approx 11.2641$}\par}} \\
        \hline
        Relación $b_{a,sp}/b$ & \vtop{\hbox{\strut \makebox[3cm][c]{$b_a/b = 0.1704$}\par }\hbox{\strut \makebox[3cm][c]{$b_{sp\;I/B}/b = 0.0900$}\par}\hbox{\strut \makebox[3cm][c]{$b_{sp\;O/B}/b = 0.3234$}\par}} & \vtop{\hbox{\strut \makebox[3cm][c]{$b_a/b \approx 0.1545$}\par }\hbox{\strut \makebox[3cm][c]{$b_{sp\;I/B}/b \approx 0.0082$}\par}\hbox{\strut \makebox[3cm][c]{$b_{sp\;O/B}/b \approx 0.3184$}\par}} & \vtop{\hbox{\strut \makebox[3cm][c]{$b_a/b \approx 0.1735$}\par }\hbox{\strut \makebox[3cm][c]{$b_{sp\;I/B}/b \approx 0.1370$}\par}\hbox{\strut \makebox[3cm][c]{$b_{sp\;O/B}/b \approx 0.3014$}\par}} & \vtop{\hbox{\strut \makebox[3cm][c]{$b_a/b \approx 0.1831$}\par }\hbox{\strut \makebox[3cm][c]{$b_{sp\;I/B}/b \approx 0.1247$}\par}\hbox{\strut \makebox[3cm][c]{$b_{sp\;O/B}/b \approx 0.3503$}\par}} \\
        \hline
        Distancia al plano de simetría del avión $y_{a,sp}$ (m) & \vtop{\hbox{\strut \makebox[3cm][c]{$y_a = 14.0599$}\par }\hbox{\strut \makebox[3cm][c]{$y_{sp\;I/B} = 4.8754$}\par}\hbox{\strut \makebox[3cm][c]{$y_{sp\;O/B} = 9.2122$}\par}} & \vtop{\hbox{\strut \makebox[3cm][c]{$y_a \approx 14.75$}\par }\hbox{\strut \makebox[3cm][c]{$y_{sp\;I/B} \approx 5.5$}\par}\hbox{\strut \makebox[3cm][c]{$y_{sp\;O/B} \approx 9.8997$}\par}} & \vtop{\hbox{\strut \makebox[3cm][c]{$y_a \approx 12.1452$}\par }\hbox{\strut \makebox[3cm][c]{$y_{sp\;I/B} \approx 3.4477$}\par}\hbox{\strut \makebox[3cm][c]{$y_{sp\;O/B} \approx 7.6789$}\par}} & \vtop{\hbox{\strut \makebox[3cm][c]{$y_a \approx 13.7388$}\par }\hbox{\strut \makebox[3cm][c]{$y_{sp\;I/B} \approx 5.1201$}\par}\hbox{\strut \makebox[3cm][c]{$y_{sp\;O/B} \approx 9.0454$}\par}} \\
        \hline
        Relación $y_{a,sp}/b$ & \vtop{\hbox{\strut \makebox[3cm][c]{$y_a/b = 0.4046$}\par }\hbox{\strut \makebox[3cm][c]{$y_{sp\;I/B}/b = 0.1403$}\par}\hbox{\strut \makebox[3cm][c]{$y_{sp\;O/B}/b = 0.2651$}\par}} & \vtop{\hbox{\strut \makebox[3cm][c]{$y_a/b \approx 0.4326$}\par }\hbox{\strut \makebox[3cm][c]{$y_{sp\;I/B}/b \approx 0.1613$}\par}\hbox{\strut \makebox[3cm][c]{$y_{sp\;O/B}/b \approx 0.2903$}\par}} & \vtop{\hbox{\strut \makebox[3cm][c]{$y_a/b \approx 0.3539$}\par }\hbox{\strut \makebox[3cm][c]{$y_{sp\;I/B}/b \approx 0.1005$}\par}\hbox{\strut \makebox[3cm][c]{$y_{sp\;O/B}/b \approx 0.2237$}\par}} & \vtop{\hbox{\strut \makebox[3cm][c]{$y_a/b \approx 0.4273$}\par }\hbox{\strut \makebox[3cm][c]{$y_{sp\;I/B}/b \approx 0.1592$}\par}\hbox{\strut \makebox[3cm][c]{$y_{sp\;O/B}/b \approx 0.2813$}\par}} \\
        \hline
        Fracción de cuerda $c_{a,sp}/c$ & \vtop{\hbox{\strut \makebox[3cm][c]{$c_a/c = 0.2372$}\par }\hbox{\strut \makebox[3cm][c]{$c_{sp\;I/B}/c = 0.1478$}\par}\hbox{\strut \makebox[3cm][c]{$c_{sp\;O/B}/c = 0.1902$}\par}} & \vtop{\hbox{\strut \makebox[3cm][c]{$c_a/c \approx 0.3333$}\par }\hbox{\strut \makebox[3cm][c]{$c_{sp\;I/B}/c \approx 0.1579$}\par}\hbox{\strut \makebox[3cm][c]{$c_{sp\;O/B}/c \approx 0.25$}\par}} & \vtop{\hbox{\strut \makebox[3cm][c]{$c_a/c \approx 0.1892$}\par }\hbox{\strut \makebox[3cm][c]{$c_{sp\;I/B}/c \approx 0.1029$}\par}\hbox{\strut \makebox[3cm][c]{$c_{sp\;O/B}/c \approx 0.1739$}\par}} & \vtop{\hbox{\strut \makebox[3cm][c]{$c_a/c \approx 0.25$}\par }\hbox{\strut \makebox[3cm][c]{$c_{sp\;I/B}/c \approx 0.12$}\par}\hbox{\strut \makebox[3cm][c]{$c_{sp\;O/B}/c \approx 0.1714$}\par}} \\
        \hline
        Coeficiente de volumen\footnote{Para calcular el coeficiente de volumen, hemos tomado $c_{a,sp}$ como la cuerda del elemento en el punto medio de su semienvergadura.} $y_ab_ac_a/(S_wb)$ & \vtop{\hbox{\strut \makebox[3cm][c]{$\eta_a =$}\par}\hbox{\strut \makebox[3cm][c]{$ \num{9.7611e-3}$}\par}\hbox{\strut \makebox[3cm][c]{$\eta_{sp\;I/B} =$}\par}\hbox{\strut \makebox[3cm][c]{$\num{2.3028e-3}$}\par}\hbox{\strut \makebox[3cm][c]{$\eta_{sp\;O/B} =$}\par}\hbox{\strut \makebox[3cm][c]{$\num{1.3864e-2}$}\par}} & \vtop{\hbox{\strut \makebox[3cm][c]{$\eta_a \approx$}\par}\hbox{\strut \makebox[3cm][c]{$ \num{1.0407e-2}$}\par}\hbox{\strut \makebox[3cm][c]{$\eta_{sp\;I/B} \approx$}\par}\hbox{\strut \makebox[3cm][c]{$\num{2.3518e-3}$}\par}\hbox{\strut \makebox[3cm][c]{$\eta_{sp\;O/B} \approx$}\par}\hbox{\strut \makebox[3cm][c]{$\num{1.8504e-2}$}\par}} & \vtop{\hbox{\strut \makebox[3cm][c]{$\eta_a \approx$}\par }\hbox{\strut \makebox[3cm][c]{$\num{7.9043e-3}$}\par}\hbox{\strut \makebox[3cm][c]{$\eta_{sp\;I/B} \approx$}\par}\hbox{\strut \makebox[3cm][c]{$\num{1.7714e-3}$}\par}\hbox{\strut \makebox[3cm][c]{$\eta_{sp\;O/B} \approx$}\par}\hbox{\strut \makebox[3cm][c]{$\num{1.1573e-2}$}\par}} & \vtop{\hbox{\strut \makebox[3cm][c]{$\eta_a \approx$}\par }\hbox{\strut \makebox[3cm][c]{$\num{1.0972e-2}$}\par}\hbox{\strut \makebox[3cm][c]{$\eta_{sp\;I/B} \approx$}\par}\hbox{\strut \makebox[3cm][c]{$\num{ 2.7852e-3}$}\par}\hbox{\strut \makebox[3cm][c]{$\eta_{sp\;O/B} \approx$}\par}\hbox{\strut \makebox[3cm][c]{$\num{1.1516e-2}$}\par}} \\
        \hline
\end{longtable}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Bibfile.bib for MWE:

```
@book{JanesA220,
    title = {Jane's All the World's Aircraft: Development \& Production},
    author = {Paul Jackson},
    year = {2016-2017},
    publisher = {IHS Markit},
}

@book{JanesA319,
    title = {Jane's All the World's Aircraft: Development \& Production},
    author = {Paul Jackson},
    year = {2007-2008},
    publisher = {IHS Markit},
}

@book{JanesB737,
    title = {Jane's All the World's Aircraft: Development \& Production},
    author = {Paul Jackson},
    year = {2012-2013},
    publisher = {IHS Markit},
}

@Manual{A319APM,
  title = {A319 Aircraft Characteristics: Airport and Maintenance Planning},
  organization = {Airbus S.A.S. Customer Services, Technical Data Support and Services},
  address = {31707, Blagnac Cedex, Francia},
  year = {Revisión Diciembre 2020},
  url = {https://www.airbus.com/aircraft/support-services/airport-operations-and-technical-data/aircraft-characteristics.html},
}

@Manual{B737APM,
  title = {737 Airplane Characteristics for Airport Planning},
  organization = {Boeing Commercial Airplanes},
  address = {North Riverside, Chicago, IL 60606, USA},
  year = {Revisión Septiembre 2020},
  url = {https://www.boeing.com/commercial/airports/plan_manuals.page},
}

@Manual{A220APM,
  title = {A220 Airport Planning Publication},
  organization = {Airbus Canada Limited Partnership Customer Services},
  address = {13100 Henri-Fabre Blvd., Mirabel, Quebec,
Canada},
  year = {Revisión Junio 2020},
  url = {A220World.airbus.com
},
}

@book{JanesCFM,
    title = {Jane's Aero-Engines},
    author = {Mark Daly \& Bill Gunston},
    year = {2012-2013},
    publisher = {IHS Markit},
}

@book{JanesP&W,
    title = {Jane's Aero-Engines},
    author = {Mark Daly},
    year = {2016-2017},
    publisher = {IHS Markit},
}

@techreport{A319TC,
    type={\unskip\space},
     title = {{Type Certificate Data Sheet No. EASA.A.064 for AIRBUS A318 – A319 – A320 – A321}},
     year = {2021},
     institution = {Agencia de la Unión Europea para la Seguridad Aérea},
}

@techreport{B737TC,
    type={\unskip\space},
     title = {Type Certificate Data Sheet No. EASA.IM.A.120
for BOEING 737},
     year = {2021},
     institution = {Agencia de la Unión Europea para la Seguridad Aérea},
}

@techreport{A220TC,
    type={\unskip\space},
     title = {Type Certificate Data Sheet No. EASA.IM.A.570 for BD-500 (A220 SERIES)},
     year = {2021},
     institution = {Agencia de la Unión Europea para la Seguridad Aérea},
}

@techreport{CFMTC,
    type={\unskip\space},
     title = {Type Certificate Data Sheet No. E.004
for CFM56-7B series engines},
     year = {2019},
     institution = {Agencia de la Unión Europea para la Seguridad Aérea},
}

@techreport{P&WTC,
    type={\unskip\space},
     title = {Type Certificate Data Sheet No. IM.E.090
for PW1500G Series Engines},
     year = {2018},
     institution = {Agencia de la Unión Europea para la Seguridad Aérea},
}

@book{Torenbeek,
    title = {Synthesis of Subsonic Airplane Design},
    author = {Egbert Torenbeek},
    year = {1982},
    publisher = {Delft University Press},
}

@misc{EurocontrolA319,
  author = {Eurocontrol},
  title = {{Aircraft Performance Database - A319-100}},
  howpublished = "\url{https://contentzone.eurocontrol.int/aircraftperformance/details.aspx?ICAO=A319}",
}

@misc{EurocontrolB737,
  author = {Eurocontrol},
  title = {{Aircraft Performance Database - B737-700}},
  howpublished = "\url{https://contentzone.eurocontrol.int/aircraftperformance/details.aspx?ICAO=B737}",
}

@misc{EurocontrolA220,
  author = {Eurocontrol},
  title = {{Aircraft Performance Database - A220-300}},
  howpublished = "\url{https://contentzone.eurocontrol.int/aircraftperformance/details.aspx?ICAO=BCS3}",
}

@book{Roskam,
    title = {Airplane Design. Part I: Preliminary Sizing of Airplanes},
    author = {Jan Roskam},
    year = {1985},
    publisher = {Design, Analysis and Research Corporation (DARcorporation)},
}

@book{Roskam2,
    title = {Airplane Design. Part II: Preliminary Sizing of Airplanes},
    author = {Jan Roskam},
    year = {1985},
    publisher = {Design, Analysis and Research Corporation (DARcorporation)},
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about the following redesign?

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 8in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[per-mode=symbol]{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{geometry}


\begin{document}


\begin{ThreePartTable}
\begin{TableNotes}
\footnotesize
\item[1] Las definiciones son análogas a las dadas para dispositivos hipersustentadores.
\item[2] Al igual que con los slats, consideramos que los spoilers externos conforman un único dispositivo. De esta manera, empleamos los subíndices $sp\;I/B$ y $sp\;O/B$ para referirnos a los spoilers interno y externos, respectivamente.
\item[3] Para calcular el coeficiente de volumen, hemos tomado $c_{a,sp}$ como la cuerda del elemento en el punto medio de su semienvergadura.
\end{TableNotes}
\begin{longtable}{wr{3cm}*{4}{S[table-format=2.4]}}
\caption{Datos de los alerones y spoilers de aviones semejantes.}
\label{aler_spoil}\\
        \toprule
        \multicolumn{5}{c}{Alerones y Spoilers\tnote{1}} \\
        \midrule
        & {Proyecto} & {A319-100} & {B737-700} & {A220-300} \\
        &            & {\cite{A319APM,JanesA319,A319TC,EurocontrolA319}} 
                                  & {\cite{B737APM,JanesB737,B737TC,EurocontrolB737}} 
                                               & {\cite{A220APM,JanesA220,A220TC,EurocontrolA220}} \\
        \midrule
\endfirsthead
\caption[]{Datos de los alerones y spoilers de aviones semejantes. -- continued from previous page}\\
        \toprule
        & {Proyecto} & {A319-100} & {B737-700} & {A220-300} \\
        &            & {\cite{A319APM,JanesA319,A319TC,EurocontrolA319}} 
                                  & {\cite{B737APM,JanesB737,B737TC,EurocontrolB737}} 
                                               & {\cite{A220APM,JanesA220,A220TC,EurocontrolA220}} \\
        \midrule
\endhead
 \insertTableNotes
 \endlastfoot
        \multicolumn{4}{@{}l}{Número de alerones por semiala} \\*
        \addlinespace
          I/B & {0} & {0} & {0} & {0} \\*
          O/B & {1} & {1} & {1} & {1} \\
        \midrule
        \multicolumn{4}{@{}l}{Número de spoilers por semiala\tnote{2}}\\*
        \addlinespace
          I/B & {1} & {1} & {1} & {1} \\*
          O/B & {4} & {4} & {5} & {4} \\
        \midrule
        \multicolumn{4}{@{}l}{Envergadura (m)} \\*
        \addlinespace
          $b_a$          & 5.9214  & 5.2692  & 5.9551  & 5.8881 \\*
          $b_{sp\;I/B}$  & 3.1275  & 2.7943  & 4.7014  & 4.0107 \\*
          $b_{sp\;O/B}$  & 11.2382 & 10.8577 & 10.3430 & 11.2641\\
        \midrule
        \multicolumn{4}{@{}l}{Relación $b_{a,sp}/b$} \\*
        \addlinespace
          $b_a/b$          & 0.1704  & 0.1545  & 0.1735  & 0.1831 \\*
          $b_{sp\;I/B}/b$  & 0.0900  & 0.0082  & 0.1370  & 0.1247 \\*
          $b_{sp\;O/B}/b$  & 0.3234  & 0.3184  & 0.3014  & 0.3503 \\
        \midrule
        \multicolumn{4}{@{}l}{Distancia al plano de simetría del avión $y_{a,sp}$ (m)}\\*
        \addlinespace
        $y_a$         & 14.0599 & 14.75  & 12.1452 & 13.7388 \\*
        $y_{sp\;I/B}$ & 4.8754  & 5.5    & 3.4477  & 5.1201 \\*
        $y_{sp\;O/B}$ & 9.2122  & 9.8997 & 7.6789  & 9.0454 \\
        \midrule
        \multicolumn{4}{@{}l}{Relación $y_{a,sp}/b$}\\*
        \addlinespace
        $y_a/b$         & 0.4046  & 0.4326  & 0.3539  & 0.4273 \\*
        $y_{sp\;I/B}/b$ & 0.1403  & 0.1613  & 0.1005  & 0.1592 \\*
        $y_{sp\;O/B}/b$ & 0.2651  & 0.2903  & 0.2237  & 0.2813 \\
        \midrule
        \multicolumn{4}{@{}l}{Fracción de cuerda $c_{a,sp}/c$ }\\*
        \addlinespace
        $c_a/c$         & 0.2372  & 0.3333  & 0.1892  & 0.25   \\*
        $c_{sp\;I/B}/c$ & 0.1478  & 0.1579  & 0.1029  & 0.12   \\*
        $c_{sp\;O/B}/c$ & 0.1902  & 0.25    & 0.1739  & 0.1714 \\
        \midrule
        \multicolumn{4}{@{}l}{Coeficiente de volumen\tnote{3}~ $y_ab_ac_a/(S_wb)$ }\\*
        \addlinespace
        $\eta_a$         & {\num{9.7611e-3}}  & {\num{1.0407e-2}}  & {\num{7.9043e-3}} & {\num{1.0972e-2}} \\*
        $\eta_{sp\;I/B}$ & {\num{2.3028e-3}}  & {\num{2.3518e-3}}  & {\num{1.7714e-3}} & {\num{2.7852e-3}} \\*
        $\eta_{sp\;O/B}$ & {\num{1.3864e-2}}  & {\num{1.8504e-2}}  & {\num{1.1573e-2}} & {\num{1.1516e-2}} \\
        \bottomrule
\end{longtable}
\end{ThreePartTable}


\end{document}
```

Comment: This is a great solution. If I wanted to add vertical lines (if necessary cutting the text onto two lines in each cell) like the original, and add a caption only at the bottom of the table, eliminate the repeated title and category lines after the page break, and center the numerical values in each, how would I go about altering your code to do that?

Answer (score 0):

- your table is to wide that can be fit in portrait nor in the landscape oriented page even if you use font size `\footnotesize`
- a possible solution is locally increase text area size and than use `landscape` oriented page
- as starting point you may consider the following solution in which is cleanup your table code and changed the text area size by use of `\newgeometry{hmargin=0.8in}`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[total={6in, 8in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}

\usepackage{pdflscape}

\begin{document}
\newgeometry{hmargin=0.8in}
    \begin{landscape}
    \sisetup{tight-spacing,
             exponent-product = \cdot
             }
\begin{talltblr}[
  caption = {Datos de los alerones y spoilers de aviones semejantes.},
  label={aler_spoil},
  note{1} = {Las definiciones son análogas a las dadas para dispositivos hipersustentadores.},
  note{2} = {Al igual que con los slats, consideramos que los spoilers externos conforman un único dispositivo. De esta manera, empleamos los subíndices $sp\;I/B$ y $sp\;O/B$ para referirnos a los spoilers interno y externos, respectivamente.},
  note{3} = {Para calcular el coeficiente de volumen, hemos tomado $c_{a,sp}$ como la cuerda del elemento en el punto medio de su semienvergadura.}
                ]{hlines, vlines,
                  colspec={X[1.1,l,h] *{4}{X[c,m]}},
                  columns = {font=\footnotesize\linespread{0.84}\selectfont},
                  row{1} ={font=\bfseries},
                  rowsep=3pt,
                  hspan =minimal
                     }
\SetCell[c=5]{c}
Alerones y Spoilers\TblrNote{1}
    &   &   &                                                           \\
    & Proyecto
        & {A319-100\\ \cite{A319APM,JanesA319,A319TC,EurocontrolA319}}
            & {B737-700\\ \cite{B737APM,JanesB737,B737TC,EurocontrolB737}}
                & {A220-300\\ \cite{A220APM,JanesA220,A220TC,EurocontrolA220}}     \\
Número de alerones por semiala
    & I/B: 0 O/B: 1 & I/B: 0 O/B: 1 & I/B: 0 O/B: 1 & I/B: 0 O/B: 1     \\
Número de spoilers por semiala\TblrNote{2}
    & I/B: 1 O/B: 4 & I/B: 1 O/B: 4 & I/B:1 O/B: 5  & I/B:1 O/B: 4      \\
Envergadura (m)
    & $\begin{aligned}
        b_a         & = 5.9214\\
        b_{sp\;I/B} & = 3.1275\\
        sp\;O/B     & = 11.2382
       \end{aligned}$
        & $\begin{aligned}
            b_a         & \approx 5.2692\\
            b_{sp\;I/B} & \approx 2.7943\\
          ~  sp\;O/B     & \approx 10.8577
           \end{aligned}$
            & $\begin{aligned}
                b_a         & \approx 5.8881\\
                b_{sp\;I/B} & \approx 4.0107\\
                sp\;O/B     & \approx 11.2641
               \end{aligned}$
                & $\begin{aligned}
                    b_a         & \approx 5.8881\\
                    b_{sp\;I/B} & \approx 4.0107\\
                    sp\;O/B     & \approx 11.2641
                   \end{aligned}$                                   \\
Relación $b_{a,sp}/b$
    & $\begin{aligned}
        b_a/b           & = 0.1704\\
        b_{sp\;I/B}/b   & = 0.0900\\
        b_{sp\;O/B}/b   & = 0.3234
     \end{aligned}$
        & $\begin{aligned}
            b_a/b           & \approx 0.1545\\
            b_{sp\;I/B}/b   & \approx 0.0082\\
            b_{sp\;O/B}/b   & \approx 0.3184
           \end{aligned}$
            & $\begin{aligned}
                b_a/b           & \approx 0.1735\\
                b_{sp\;I/B}/b   & \approx 0.1370\\
                b_{sp\;O/B}/b   & \approx 0.3014
              \end{aligned}$
                & $\begin{aligned}
                    b_a/b           & \approx 0.1831\\
                    b_{sp\;I/B}/b   & \approx 0.1247\\
                    b_{sp\;O/B}/b   & \approx 0.3503
                  \end{aligned}$                                    \\
Distancia al plano de simetría del avión $y_{a,sp}$ (m)
    & $\begin{aligned}
        y_a         & = 14.0599\\
        y_{sp\;I/B} & = 4.8754\\
        y_{sp\;O/B} & = 9.2122
     \end{aligned}$
        & $\begin{aligned}
            y_a         & \approx 14.75\\
            y_{sp\;I/B} & \approx 5.5\\
            y_{sp\;O/B} & \approx 9.8997
           \end{aligned}$
            & $\begin{aligned}
                y_a         & \approx 12.1452\\
                y_{sp\;I/B} & \approx 3.4477\\
                y_{sp\;O/B} & \approx 7.6789
               \end{aligned}$
                & $\begin{aligned}
                    y_a         & \approx 13.7388\\
                    y_{sp\;I/B} & \approx 5.1201\\
                    y_{sp\;O/B} & \approx 9.0454
               \end{aligned}$                                       \\
Relación $y_{a,sp}/b$
    & $\begin{aligned}
        y_a/b         & = 0.4046\\
        y_{sp\;I/B}/b & = 0.1403\\
        y_{sp\;O/B}/b & = 0.2651
     \end{aligned}$
        & $\begin{aligned}
            y_a/b         & \approx 0.4326\\
            y_{sp\;I/B}/b & \approx 0.1613\\
            y_{sp\;O/B}/b & \approx 0.2903
           \end{aligned}$
            & $\begin{aligned}
                y_a/b         & \approx 0.3539\\
                y_{sp\;I/B}/b & \approx 0.1005\\
                y_{sp\;O/B}/b & \approx 0.2237
               \end{aligned}$
                & $\begin{aligned}
                    y_a/b         & \approx 0.4273\\
                    y_{sp\;I/B}/b & \approx 0.1592\\
                    y_{sp\;O/B}/b & \approx 0.2813
               \end{aligned}$                                       \\
Fracción de cuerda $c_{a,sp}/c$
    & $\begin{aligned}
        c_a/c         & = 0.2372\\
        c_{sp\;I/B}/c & = 0.1478\\
        c_{sp\;O/B}/c & = 0.1902
     \end{aligned}$
        & $\begin{aligned}
            c_a/c         & \approx 0.3333\\
            c_{sp\;I/B}/c & \approx 0.1579\\
            c_{sp\;O/B}/c & \approx 0.25
           \end{aligned}$
                & $\begin{aligned}
                c_a/c         & \approx 0.1892\\
                c_{sp\;I/B}/c & \approx 0.1029\\
                c_{sp\;O/B}/c & \approx 0.173
               \end{aligned}$
                & $\begin{aligned}
                    c_a/c         & \approx 0.25\\
                    c_{sp\;I/B}/c & \approx 0.12\\
                    c_{sp\;O/B}/c & \approx 0.1714
                   \end{aligned}$                                   \\
Coeficiente de volumen\TblrNote{3} $y_ab_ac_a/(S_wb)$
    & $\begin{aligned}
    \eta_a         & = \num{9.7611e-3}\\
    \eta_{sp\;I/B} & = \num{2.3028e-3}\\
    \eta_{sp\;O/B} & = \num{1.3864e-2}
     \end{aligned}$
        & $\begin{aligned}
        \eta_a         & \approx \num{1.0407e-2}\\
        \eta_{sp\;I/B} & \approx \num{2.3518e-3}\\
        \eta_{sp\;O/B} & \approx \num{1.8504e-2}
         \end{aligned}$
            & $\begin{aligned}
                \eta_a         & \approx \num{7.9043e-3}\\
                \eta_{sp\;I/B} & \approx \num{1.7714e-3}\\
                \eta_{sp\;O/B} & \approx \num{1.1573e-2}
               \end{aligned}$
                & $\begin{aligned}
                    \eta_a         & \approx \num{1.0972e-2}\\
                    \eta_{sp\;I/B} & \approx \num{ 2.7852e-3}\\
                    \eta_{sp\;O/B} & \approx \num{1.1516e-2}
                   \end{aligned}$                                   \\
\end{talltblr}
    \end{landscape}
\restoregeometry
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Solid reply. Unfortunately I need a portrait table because I have this in a list of portrait tables, this being the only one that doesn't fit.  But this is a great table to include in an annex, thanks!

Comment: To whom downvote answer: why? What is wrong with answer? Please, enlighten me.